# Fuzzy autocompletion in Intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2015, intellisense

I am working in a C# Project with **Visual Studio Community 2015**.

I wonder if I can enable fuzzy matching for the Intellisense completion.

For example, if I type `madeco` then the completion should propose `max_device_count`.

I have come across the JetBrains' Resharper plugin that does exactly this, but I am reserved installing it, because it's a 3rd party tool and seems to be quite heavy-weighted.

#### Example

Example C# Class:

```
class A
{
  int max_bytes = 0;
  int max_device_count = 0;
  int max_workers = 0;

  public A()
  {
    // 1. Typing 'ma' proposes 'max_bytes',
    //    and in the list I see 'max_device_count' and 'max_workers'

    // 2. Typing 'max_d' proposes 'max_device_count'

    // 3. Typing 'madeco' should fuzzy match 'max_device_count', but it does not
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, do you mean define the max_device_count and then type madeco in C++ project? If so, the VS default intellisense works as your expected, please check this: https://1drv.ms/i/s!Atv5QNuFrncKgyNYmr59X30I1cpT, if I misunderstand your meaning, please provide more detail information, thanks.

Comment: I am working in a C# project. Yes, if I have defined a member variable called "max_device_count" and then typing 'madeco' should propose 'max_device_count' and when hitting enter it should be inserted into the code.

However, when typing 'madeco' I get the last matching variable name, which might different, like 'max_bytes', ... 

I edit the example in my question for more clarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the VS 2015/2017 15.2/2017 15.3 and found the fuzzy mode have be added into 2017 15.3 version, please check the following:
[image]

Please download [the VS 2017 15.3](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) and it should work as your expected.